# A representation is reducible if is equivalent to another reducible

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $\rho$ and $\pi$ be equivalent representations of the group G over F.
Prove that if $\rho$ is reducible then $\pi$ is reducible.

Liebeck and James prove this property using matrix representantion of linear transformation, since reducible representations are equivalent to a block matrix. I tried another way:

Let $\{v_{1},..,v_{k},v_{k+1},..,v_{n}\}$ be a basis of a vector space $V=F^{n}$. Since $\rho$ is reducible, there is a invariant subspace of V under $\rho g$, for all $g\in G$, say $W=span\{v_{1},...,v_{k}\}$. Then exists $(\alpha_{ij})$ for each $g\in G$ such that $(\rho g)v_{j}=\sum^{k}_{i=1}\alpha_{ij}v_{i}$, for $i,j\in\{1,...,k\}$, and there is a linear transformation $T\in GL(V)$ such that $T(\rho g)T^{-1}=(\pi g)$.

Define $T(v_{j})=u_{j}$. Since $T$ is an isomorphism, the set $\{u_{1},...,u_{n}\}$ is linearly independent. Hence, $(\rho g)T^{-1}(u_{j})=(\rho g)v_{j}=\sum^{k}_{i=1}\alpha_{ij}v_{i}$, then

$T(\rho g)T^{-1}(u_{j})=(\pi g)v_{j}=\sum^{k}_{i=1}\alpha_{ij}T(v_{i})=\sum^{k}_{i=1}\alpha_{ij}u_{i}$. We conclude that $U=span\{u_{1},...,u_{k}\}$ is a FG-submodule of $\pi$.

Is this suffice to prove that $\pi$ is reducible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things by choosing a basis. In algebra, whenever you have two isomorphic objects you can use the isomorphism to "transfer" basically any property or structure to the first object to one for the second object.

In your case, $\rho : G \to GL(V_\rho)$ and $\pi : G \to GL(V_\pi)$ are two representations on vector spaces $V_\rho$ and $V_\pi$ and you have an isomorphism $T: V_\rho \to V_\pi$ between them, which you can use to transfer from $\rho$ to $\pi$ anything that is defined in terms of your representations. If $W_\rho$ is an invariant subspace of $V_\rho$, then you get a corresponding subspace $W_\pi = T(W_\rho)$ of $V_\pi$. I'll let you check explicitly that $T(W_\rho)$ is indeed an invariant subspace, but this should be "obvious" since the property of being an invariant subspace is just transferred by $T$.